# update richtextbox using thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml

I made small c# project using xaml.
To append text at richtextbox every 1 second in thread function, i used BeginInvoke.
but it is updated after done thread. i need to update every 1 sec
Log is name of richtextbox.

```
private void Worker3()
{
    int nCnt = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        nCnt++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart)delegate ()
            {                             
                Log.AppendText("Updating..." + nCnt.ToString()); 
            }
        );

    }
}

private void Thread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker3));
    thread1.Start();

    // Wait for the worker thread to finish
    thread1.Join();
}
```

help me. thanks

I want code that update every 1 second.

Comment: Delete the line with the join. You are blocking event handling.

Comment: If ever you write `while (true) { ... Thread.Sleep ... }` style code then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Join` on the thread, that will block until that thread completes. That means that no other code can be executed on the UI thread until that `Join` call returns, so all your `BeginInvoke` calls will simply queue up waiting to be executed, which won't happen until the thread completes, Join returns and the UI thread is free again. DO NOT call `Join`.

You really ought to learn how to use tasks rather than threads. You can await a task without locking up the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do something periodically is to use a *timer*. If you are using WPF you should likely use [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) that invokes the event on the UI thread:

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

...
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nCnt++;
    Log.AppendText("Updating..." + nCnt.ToString()); 
}
```

There are other methods to handle things like long running operations that produce a result, progress reporting, or a background thread that continuously updates. But for a simple "update text ever second", a dispatchtimer is the correct solution.